# OpenTK.Graphics.GraphicsContextException

Tags: c#, visual-studio, monogame

[image]

Is all I'm getting once the game crashes, It started happening few weeks ago, but I didn't mind it because it happened once in a blue moon. But now it's happening every few seconds, and its really frustrating. I don't know what is causing it and I cant find any information regarding it.

At first I thought simple re-install of monogame will fix it, but yesterday I formatted my pc, installed windows 10, new visual studio and fresh new Monogame, and its still happening! Anyone knows what this is and what can I do?

Comment: Does it happen with all monogame projects, or just this one? Can you give a sample game that causes this error?

Comment: @31eee384 its my first project so I don't know, I will post all the code if needed, but before that I will try to create windows project instead of openGL one because from google it seem like its openGL problem.

Comment: Maybe this will help? https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/issues/741